# MATLAB: per-edge transparency and per-edge color on patch object

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

As my rendering was getting slow because it used a massive number of patch objects, I followed the recommendation of aggregating all my patches into a single one and that provided a massive boost in rendering speed.

I want to be able to hide part of the patch but unfortunately I can only modify the per-face transparency (using `p.FaceVertexAlphaData`) NOT the per-edge transparency . It there any way to set transparency on a per edge basis?

Similarly is there any way of setting the color on a per-edge basis?

The best I could do so far is set color on a per vertex basis and set 'EdgeAlpha'to interp - ie tie the alpha of the vertices to the alpha of the edges

```
figure; 
alim([0 1]);
v = [2 4; 2 8; 8 4; 5 0; 5 2; 8 0];
f = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
col = [0; 1];    
alpha = [1;1;1;1;1;1];    
p = patch('Faces',f,'Vertices',v,'FaceVertexCData',col,'FaceColor','flat', ...
   'FaceVertexAlphaData', alpha, 'FaceAlpha', 'interp', ...
  'EdgeAlpha', 'interp');

p.FaceVertexAlphaData(4:end) = 1;
p.FaceVertexAlphaData(1:3) = 0; % hide...
```

Comment: Can you show a visual example of how a vertex with alpha would look like? I am not sure if its of any use, as they are very thin lines. They are most likely stored as vector lines inside Matlab.

Comment: Do I understand right -> you want a transparency gradient?

Comment: I don't want a gradient. I want to hide some edges (like I can hide some faces). I also would like to color some edges differently than others.